# Locking visual update on Grid while adding children to it

Tags: xamarin.forms

When I add children (cells) to a grid, I can see the grid adding rows and columns. 
While this looked very cool at first, it makes the app appear acting slowly.

I would therefore like to know if there's a way to lock the visual update, hoping that this will also make populating the Grid faster.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: My only proposal would be to create new class inheriting `Grid`, override [`Layout.ShouldInvalidateOnChildAdded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.layout.shouldinvalidateonchildadded?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Layout_ShouldInvalidateOnChildAdded_Xamarin_Forms_View_) and force layout update once you're done.

Comment: @orhtej2 Thank you. Could you make your comment the answer? And perhaps add some more info on how to do that exactely (only if you want, but would be great!)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the layout calculation is a problem here - its the first time rendering that involves too many steps like assigning renderers and all that could be causing the lag. The bigger the Visual tree, the worse it gets.

You can try detaching your `Grid` from its `Parent`, make your updates, and then add it back to intended parent (this should ensure the rendering updates are suspended).

```
//first detach from visual tree
var parent = currentGrid.Parent as ContentView;
parent.Conent = null;

//do your updates to grid control here

//now attach it back to visual tree
parent.Content = currentGrid;
```

Another option is to (as @orhtej2 mentioned) extend your `Grid` control to suspend layout calculations. Not sure if it will help with rendering performance though.

```
public class SmartGrid : Grid
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty SuspendLayoutProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
        "SuspendLayout", typeof(bool), typeof(SmartGrid),
        defaultValue: default(bool), propertyChanged: OnSuspendLayoutChanged);

    public bool SuspendLayout
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(SuspendLayoutProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SuspendLayoutProperty, value); }
    }

    static void OnSuspendLayoutChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        ((SmartGrid)bindable).OnSuspendLayoutChangedImpl((bool)oldValue, (bool)newValue);
    }

    protected virtual void OnSuspendLayoutChangedImpl(bool oldValue, bool newValue)
    {
        InvalidateLayout();
    }

    protected override void InvalidateLayout()
    {
        if(!SuspendLayout)
            base.InvalidateLayout();
    }

    protected override void InvalidateMeasure()
    {
        if (!SuspendLayout)
            base.InvalidateMeasure();
    }

    protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
        if (!SuspendLayout)
            base.LayoutChildren(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Sample usage would look like:

```
//first detach from visual tree
var parent = currentGrid.Parent as ContentView;
parent.Conent = null;

currentGrid.SuspendLayout = true;
//do your updates to grid control here
currentGrid.SuspendLayout = false;

//now attach it back to visual tree
parent.Content = currentGrid;
```